# Contest Problem - Min cost matching?

Tags: algorithms

I have some questions regarding this old contest problem:
[Problem](http://usaco.org/index.php?page=viewproblem2&cpid=248),
[Solution](http://usaco.org/current/data/sol_taxi.html)

I don't quite understand the second paragraph of the second solution which begins with "Unfortunately, the permutation...".
Could anyone explain this part?

Comment: Please make the question self-contained, so we understand what you are asking without having to click on links.  If those links stop working, we want this question to remain meaningful and understandable.

Comment: Also, it would help if you could give us more to work with.  Why didn't you understand that part?  What do you understand?  What is your interpretation, and why didn't that make sense to you?  The more you can help us narrow down what your confusion might be, the more likely that you will get help from someone here.